# Touchpad frozen after resume on a Gateway MX6650/MA2A

Tags: 10.10, resume, trackpad, sleep

After the computer is resumed from sleep, the trackpad no longer works. I've tried different settings using the s2ram command, just to see if it would change anything. But that doesn't seem to be the problem. Where else do I check?

Comment: Did you ever get this fixed?  I'm having the same problem in xubuntu 13.04.

Comment: I no longer have access to this computer. I don't think I ever got that working right, so I'm afraid if none of the answers below work, I can't be of much assistance, sorry :(

Answer (score 1):

Look at the `pm-powersave` package, and see [Why is wireless down/strange after switching to battery or closing/opening the lid?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65632/why-is-wireless-down-strange-after-switching-to-battery) for some help.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a problem with your ACPI ; Here is a workaround when your trackpad is frozen : Open a terminal (ALT+F2 gnome-terminal) and enter :

```
sudo rmmod psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse
```