# Why is wireless down/strange after switching to battery or closing/opening the lid?

Tags: wireless, power-management

I noticed that, when I unplugged my laptop, or closed/opened the lid, my wireless connection dropped, every time.

I tracked it down to `pm-powersave`, and made it stop, see below.

This could also cause repeated requests for network passwords.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer to this question instead of including it in your question.

Comment: Well done, that's the way to self-document, woo!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've found that `/usr/sbin/pm-powersave` turns **OFF** my wireless card when I switch to battery or suspend by closing the laptop's lid. I've gotten wireless to stay up between hibernates by executing `sudo /usr/sbin/pm-powersave false`. The `man pm-powersave` page says I can create an empty file `/etc/pm/power.d/wireless` to prevent `/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/wireless` from running and doing its **magic**. I've done it, and it works for me.

I found this by doing an `ls -lrt /var/log` just after the event, and looking at the last 100 so lines of the recently modified logs. I use this technique to start answering **many** questions about what my system just did.