# Hibernation causes crashing on an Acer Aspire

Tags: 11.10, acer, hibernate

Hibernation worked perfectly fine in 11.04. Ever since I upgraded to 11.10, my laptop (Acer Aspire) keeps crashing when it's hibernating. I have no clue why. Any ideas?

At first it seemed to only happen between 6a-noon (US Eastern time), but this morning it happened earlier.

(PS. I checked `/var/log/syslog` but I'm not sure what I'm looking for. I thought something might jump out at me as an obvious error in hibernating or coming out of it, but nothing seemed unusual. I'm a bit of a newbie in this area so I might be missing something in lines upon lines upon lines.)

Comment: We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information?

Comment: Rather than `/var/log/syslog`, look at `/var/log/pm-*.log`, and the files listed by `dpkg -L pm-utils`, also see my other answer http://askubuntu.com/questions/65632/why-is-wireless-down-strange-after-switching-to-battery/65815#65815 which offers more detail.

Comment: Have you tried installing a newer kernel? That helped me. You can post your log in pastebin , too

Comment: What do you mean with crashing?

Comment: i had a lot of problems with hibernating with the same acer aspire (4810tz) and i had to disable it. But with the 11.10 i'm not having any kind of issue.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 1):

I am a beginner for ubuntu itself and I don't know whether I am right, but it looks like that there might be a compatibility issue with a hardware or a setting in your bios. I would recommend to check your bios settings and make sure that you have your ACPI settings (I don't know how to do it yet in Ubuntu, but I'll update my post on the moment I discover). A simple device on your usb port or a new driver on one of the peripherals can cause this. If you have hardware that needs proprietary drivers, you might need to update them too. Also, check the ACPI settings and set it to S3.

Maybe this can help: http://www.ubuntugeek.com/fix-for-suspend-and-hibernation-problem-for-laptops.html

Also, it might be a little bit useful for the more experts if you provide your hardware and software information. Also, state your bios type (Phoenix or American trends or xEFI).

Comment: Where should that ACPI setting be set to S3? In the BIOS settings or somewhere in Ubuntu system?

Comment: In BIOS. systen resume option should be your choice. Most probably underthe advanced settings or power settings.

Comment: I don't have "S3". The only thing I found was Power on By PS/2 Keyboard -> Disabled, Power on by PS/2 Mouse -> Disabled, Restore AC Power Loss -> Power Off (and some more options)

Could it be that?