# black screen after waking up from suspend

Tags: 11.10, suspend, screen

running 11.10 and on wake up after being suspended (for a long time or 2 seconds, doesn't matter) I am presented with a black screen that just has a purple bar (about the size of the top menu bar). As far as I can tell the system is unresponsive to anything outside of a manual restart by pressing the power button on the tower, after which it starts normally. using the most up to date graphics driver, also tried switching to a different version, nothing.

Comment: Can you provide more details on your system? make, model, type of graphics card, that sort of thing. Thanks!

Comment: I have the same symptoms with a Toshiba satellite u400.  Problem also raises if i have my laptop screen of and I change the mode of my dual screen after wake up

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closure. =)

Comment: I had this problem as well. I found 11.10 a bit too buggy for my taste, and don't prefer it. I'd recommend downgrading to 10.04 if you're willing. I found 10.04 to be very bug free, and much faster than it's more flashy successor.

Answer (score 1):

The black screen error

1. If you found such error, you can just shake you mouse one or two times, the black screen goes away and come the login session.
2. This might occur because of the Power Management setting you have changed or by the default setting.
3. When there is no activity in the system for 1 hour or so(this is based on Power Management setting) ... This might occur.

Answer (score 0):

It could be Power Manager related, see my answer [Why is wireless down/strange after switching to battery or closing/opening the lid?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65632/why-is-wireless-down-strange-after-switching-to-battery)

Power Manager is also invoked for suspend/resume, so the answer should help.

Comment: was looking at the /var/log/pm-suspend.log like waltinator suggested and comparing it to another that i found online and i noticed that no resume suspend action is running just shows the suspend suspend ones

Comment: Look again. The scripts in `/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/` are run both at suspend (with a parameter of "false") and at resume (with a parameter of "true").

Comment: @waltinator When the machine is improperly shut down, data (logs) are lost.