# Prevent airplane mode from turning on when lid is closed in ubuntu gnome 17.04

Tags: gnome, power-management, 17.04, airplane-mode

None of the methods described in the link work [Prevent wireless from turning off when lid goes down](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100628/prevent-wireless-from-turning-off-when-lid-goes-down)

Power management from `iwconfig` is OFF.
Any suggestions, what else can be done?

Comment: Use the answer for preventing sleep didn't work?

Comment: No, it didn't. The laptop doesn't sleep. The lid closed is supposed to 'do nothing'. But the airplane mode is switched on instantly after the lid is closed.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/965596/459667 Use this answer. It will help. Moreover, if not, try locking screen and then closing lid. This will make wifi    work in backgroud.

Comment: Vivek Ji should post this as an answer instead of a comment. This is what works. (method 2 is what i used)

Answer (score 1):

This guide is what helped solve the issue for me: http://tipsonubuntu.com/2018/04/28/change-lid-close-action-ubuntu-18-04-lts/

Basically, open your preferences using `sudo gedit /etc/systemd/logind.conf` and change the line starting with `HandleLidSwitch` to `HandleLidSwitch=ignore`

Comment: Doesn't stop airplane mode

Answer (score 1):

1. Run:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/UPower/UPower.conf
   ```
2. Set:

   ```
   IgnoreLid=true
   ```
3. If on `systemd`, issue the following command:

   ```
   sudo service upower restart
   ```

Comment: Still getting airplane mode

Answer (score 0):

The issue is still around on Ubuntu 20.04 with the latest kernel `5.4.0-51-generic`, and perhaps other distros as well. It's a long standing bug (there is at least one [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1781049) describing this behavior) with rather slim chances of being fixed, IMHO.

Some people report to have fixed it via BIOS settings, others - via blacklisting some or all of the `wmi,hp-wmi,hp-wireless` modules. None of the ad-hoc fixes have worked for me so far - blacklisting kernel modules, messing with `setkeycodes`, custom `systemd` services etc. etc.

Long story short, as @TWinters has pointed out, the only workaround is to avoid the network controller going in "hard blocked" mode in the first place. Once `RF_KILL bit toggled to disable radio` occurs, the only remedies are a hardware switch or reboot.

Since the "hardware switch" governed by `hp-wireless` usually does not work (e.g. fn+F12), the only way out appears to be disabling suspend on lid close or power button events.

Comment: I can't follow this answer. How do I do this "the only workaround is to avoid the network controller going in "hard blocked" mode"?