# Permanently disable Airplane mode

Tags: bluetooth, wifi-hardware-switch, airplane-mode

I'm having a problem finding a way to permanently disable the Airplane mode feature. Every time I close my HP Stream laptop's lid it goes into airplane mode, so no emails are incoming. Strangely there seems to be no option to prevent this from happening in Ubuntu, so I wonder if there's a way to permanently disable Airplane mode.

Comment: check your power settings

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does "Airplane Mode" keep toggling on my HP laptop in Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/965595/why-does-airplane-mode-keep-toggling-on-my-hp-laptop-in-ubuntu-18-04) or https://askubuntu.com/questions/970120/prevent-airplane-mode-from-turning-on-when-lid-is-closed-in-ubuntu-gnome-17-04

Comment: Thank you so much. Finally. I did not realize that that also solver my problem because it was addressing a screen-rotation issue, and i didnt wanted to mess something without knowing it would fit my needs... but it turns out that it does, so thanxs.

Answer (score 0):

Quite hacky but working solution.

```
crontab -e
```

inside write:

```
* * * * * /usr/sbin/rfkill unblock all
```

I tries to unblock wifi and bluetooth every minute.

And maybe you need to add user to the `rfkill` group (Ubuntu 20.04 work well without that).