# Ubuntu 18.04 goes to aeroplane mode when I close the lid

Tags: 18.04, wireless, bluetooth

Using GNOME tweak tool, I have already selected `off` to 'Suspend when laptop lid is closed'. So, the system doesn't suspend. But, when I close the lid and reopen it, system goes in aeroplane mode and hence WiFi and bluetooth get disconnected.

I already tried [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1378917/ubuntu-18-04-closing-laptop-lid-stops-wi-fi-connection) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100628/prevent-wireless-from-turning-off-when-lid-goes-down). But, those didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. (Do you have a HP laptop?)

The next steps will test if you have the same problem as I had and also will provide solution. It is based in a very useful comment from usser "ebin92" on reddit about this topic.

**TEST**

*We gonna check if the open/close lid event is sending scancodes and, if so, remap them*

- Open a terminal and type: `<journalctl -f>`
- Then open and close the lid, and check in the terminal for an unknown scancode (in my case they were "e058" and "e057")
- Remap the scancodes that your lid are sending to DISPLAY OFF code (you can remap it to another keycode if you want)
  For that, use >> `setkeycodes [SCANCODE] [KEYCODE]`
  In my case, >> `setkeycodes e058 245 e057 245`

Try again opening and closing your lid and if the problem is solved, lets make it permanent.

**PERMANENT FIX**

*We are going to enable a new systemd service to remap the scancodes on boot up*

- Open a terminal and go to /etc/systemd/system. Execute next steps as superuser
- Create a new file with name format "YOURNAME.service". In my case it was "lidbehaviour_override.service"
- Put inside the attached content (see below) and edit the keycodes to your case
- Give to the file execution permissions, running >> `sudo chdmod a+x FILENAME`
  In my case >> `sudo chdmod a+x lidbehaviour_override.service`
- Test everything is fine running the service. For that:
  · reload the daemon configuration (all you have modified in systemd) with `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`
  · run the new service with `sudo systemctl start YOURNAME.service`
  In my case `systemctl start lidbehaviour_override.service`
  · Open and close the lid
- If everything went right, then make the service starts on boot up `sudo systemctl enable YOURNAME.service`
  In my case `systemctl enable lidbehaviour_override.service`

**SYSTEMD SERVICE CONTENT**

```
[Unit]
Description=Fix aeroplane mode on/off when lid opens/closes

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/setkeycodes e058 245 e057 245

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: ABSOLUTELY FANTASTIC!!! It worked on my HP laptop, thank you!!