# Laptop camera (/dev/video) not there after suspend - reboot needed to get it back

Tags: power-management, suspend

Camera stops working on my laptop after suspend and wake. I have to restart to get it back. When listing the `/dev/` directory there is no `/dev/video` after wake. Is there a way to get it back without restarting since I practically use suspend instead shutdown?

Answer (score 0):

Suspend/wake events are handled by the `pm-utils` package. See my answer [Why is wireless down/strange after switching to battery or closing/opening the lid?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65632/why-is-wireless-down-strange-after-switching-to-battery-or-closing-opening-the-l/65815), but change "wireless" to "video" or "camera", as needed.

Comment: Thanks. I'll accept/upvote the answer in next few days if I see that the problem is not reoccurring.

Comment: Unfortunately the /dev/video0 still disappears.